# why Expression.Lambda().Compile() faster then origin

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

test class O:

```
class O
{
    public int o;
}
```

action 1:

```
var in1 = new Action<O, int>((a, b) => a.o = b);
```

action 2:

```
var p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(O));
var p2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
var k = Expression.Assign(Expression.Field(p1, typeof(O).GetField("o")), p2);
var in2 = Expression.Lambda<Action<O, int>>(k, p1, p2).Compile();
```

test method:

```
void Test(int iteration, Action action)
{
    var watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();
    for (var i = 0; i < iteration; i++) action();
    watch.Stop();
    // print
}
```

then test:

```
var o = new O();
Time(1000000000, () => in1(o, 8)) // 8273 ms
Time(1000000000, () => in2(o, 8)) // 6603 ms
```

so why in2() faster then in1() ?!?!?

Comment: I tried that, but I'm not measuring any significant difference.

Comment: I tried and I have a slightly bigger  difference than OP

Comment: Release build produces less impressive difference, but it is there.

Comment: I **guess** in debug build, VS must maintain code location for `in1` while not for `in2`. In release build, `in1` is faster than `in2` on machine. It makes sense compiler optimize better than run-time.

Comment: The two are 100% identical. Benchmarking is a lot harder than you seem to think :)

Comment: @Luaan, when I inspect generated delegate, there are slight signature difference. The second action includes a `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure` as parameter. They are semantically the same, but are not 100% identical.